# How to make something rotate based on where another object is

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a scrolling background type of game, kind of like Mario. I have a character that walks on the ground and can go left or right, and I want to introduce a flying eyeball that is suspended in the sky that follows the character's movements. I have an eyeball png (the eye of chuthulhu from Terraria). All I want it to do is rotate based on where the character is, and seem to stare at it (the next step is to have it shoot lasers at the character). How would I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [PyGame function](https://web.archive.org/web/20200423183702/https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotate) `pygame.transform.rotate()` or `pygame.transform.rotozoom()` to pre-create rotated versions of your eyeball.

It sounds like the eyeball will pass over the top of the player when the player changes walking directions (since it's always following).  So simply comparing the difference in sideways-position between the player and the eyeball should be enough to determine which of the pre-rotated eyeball images to choose.

If the eyeball's X co-ordinate is a long way from the player, then a slight angle is needed.  As the player gets closer to having the eyeball above them, the angle should change to the point where the eye is looking straight down.  This corresponds to the difference between the eyeball-X and player-X being small (tending towards zero).

Maybe even a simple mapping table between X-difference and sprite-image would be enough.

Comment: I understand what you mean for the most part about the angle changing based on the distance between the 2 sprites, but I don't really understand how to change the angle based on this distance. The eye is flying over the character while shooting at it.